# Cypher Query where 2 different labels do not contain a relationship to a 3rd label/node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jrb

I have 3 labels, A, B, and Z.  A & B both have a relationship to Z.  I want to find all the A nodes that do not have share any of nodes Z in common with B

Currently, doing a normal query where the relationship DOES exist, works.

```
MATCH (a:A)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b:B { uuid: {<SOME ID>} })
RETURN DISTINCT a
```

But when I do

```
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b:B { uuid: {<SOME ID>} }))
RETURN DISTINCT a
```

It throws an error

```
Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError: z not defined
```

Not sure if the syntax for this is incorrect, I tried `WHERE NOT EXIST()` but no luck.

***The query is part of a larger one called through a rails app using neo4jrb / (Neo4j::Session.query)***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem to do with the scope of your query. When you describe a node in a `MATCH` clause like the below

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel)
```

You're telling cypher to look for a node with the label `SomeLabel`, and assign it to the variable `n` in the rest of the query, and at the end of the query, you can return the values stored in this node using `RETURN n` (unless you drop `n` by not including it in a `WITH` clause).

Later on in you query, if you want to `MATCH` another node, you can do it in reference to `n`, so for example:

```
MATCH (m:SomeOtherLabel)-[:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]-(n)
```

Will match a variable connected (in any direction) to the node `n`, with a label `SomeOtherLabel`, and assign it to the variable `m` for the rest of the query.

You can only assign nodes to variables like this in `MATCH`, `OPTIONAL MATCH`, `MERGE`, `CREATE` and (sort of) in `WITH` and `UNWIND` clauses (someone correct me here if I've missed one, I suppose you also do this in list comprehensions and `FOREACH` clauses).

In your second query, you are trying to find a node with the label `A`, which is not connected to a node with the label `Z`. However, the way you have written the query means that you are actually saying **find a node with label `A` which is not connected via a `rel1` relationship to the node stored as `z`**. This will fail (and as shown, neo complains that `z` is not defined), because you can't create a new variable like this in the `WHERE` clause.

To correct your error, you need to remove the reference to the variable `z`, and ensure you have also defined the variable `b` containing your node before the `WHERE` clause. Now, you keep the label in the query, like the below.

```
MATCH (a:A)
MATCH (b:B { uuid: {<SOME ID>} })
WHERE NOT (a)-[:rel1]->(:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b) // changed this line
RETURN DISTINCT a
```

And with a bit of luck, this will now work.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly!  Still relatively new to Cypher/Neo4j.  Trying to speed a report that is chugging because of loops and over use of neo4jrb's ActiveNode calls.

On the opposite side of above,  I have a query to get where A & B's relationshps to Z match. Easy enough.  How would I combine a query to bring back a collection of Z's where they match and another collection of the remaining unmatching Z's?  If the current is working query to get the matched rels is...

MATCH (a:A)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(:B { uuid: {<ID>} })
RETURN DISTINCT a, collect({match: z.title})

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because z is the identifier of a node that you are using in a where clause that you have not yet identified.

Since you know **b** already I would match it first and then use it in your where clause. You don't need to assign `:Z` an identifier, simply using the node label will suffice.

```
MATCH (b:B { uuid: {<SOME ID>} })
WITH b
MATCH (a:A)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:rel1]->(:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b)
RETURN DISTINCT a
```